# Trying to find out if Git is installed via Powershell?

Tags: git, powershell

I have this short combination of cmdlets(?) that tells by counting how many returns I get, but it only works if Git was installed in the $Env:Path.

I want to use `git rev-parse --short HEAD`, but check if it is installed beforehand in a PS script.

```
# $gitInstalled = "git" | Get-Command -CommandType Application -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | measure; 
# Write-Host $count.Count;
```

I realize it pretty much answers the question by itself, But I want to know if there is another way, more efficient or broadly covering, to find out if Git is installed?

Edit: So we can shorten the command to just

```
# $gitInstalled = Get-Command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue git
```

Comment: Run `git version` in Powershell?

Comment: Running something like `$a = git --version` in a PS script when `git` is not in the PATH variable will result in 
    `git : The term 'git' is not recognized...`

Comment: Run `git version` and then test the value of `$?`. It's `True` or `False`.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Why not `Get-Command git`? Keep in mind that git could be _installed_ but not added to `%PATH%`

Comment: If git is not in your path, then the only way you can find it is if you know exactly where you expect it to be installed. (Or am I missing something fundamental in your question?) In that case, you can just check for the presence of `C:\Program Files\path\to\git\bin\git.exe`.

Comment: you could also try to get path from registry like [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/GVFS/blob/master/GVFS/GVFS.Common/Git/GitProcess.cs). But it would fail if a portable git is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the registry for the installed programs by looking at the [Uninstall keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
Function Test-IsGitInstalled
{
    $32BitPrograms = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
    $64BitPrograms = Get-ItemProperty     HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
    $programsWithGitInName = ($32BitPrograms + $64BitPrograms) | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.DisplayName -and $_.Displayname.Contains('Git') }
    $isGitInstalled = $null -ne $programsWithGitInName
    return $isGitInstalled
}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$isGitInstalled = $null -ne ( (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*) + (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*) | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.DisplayName -and $_.Displayname.Contains('Git') })
```

Answer (score 10):

You can just see if the command is available:

```
try
{
    git | Out-Null
   "Git is installed"
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]
{
    "No git"
}
```

This also happens to cover the additional question, "Is git in $env:path?"